# Testing DOM Ready with Teaspoon and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, jasmine, teaspoon

I'm writing tests using Teaspoon and Jasmine for my Rails app.  I understand, for the most part, how to test standalone js modules but I'm not sure how to go about testing a module that binds to a DOM ready event like with JQuery's `$(document).ready()`.

Ideally I could set up a fixture before requiring the JS file, but if I don't put the `require` as the first statement, then it is ignored.

How does one usually go about testing this?

I would've wanted to do something like:

**cool.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".stuff").click(stuffClickHandler);
}
```

**cool_spec.js:**

```
fixture.load("fixture_with_stuffs.html");
//= require cool
describe("on ready", function() {
  it("should bind handlers to all stuffs", function() {
    // test stuffs for handlers
  });
});
```

But that doesn't work, because if the `//= require` comes after anything, it doesn't seem to load the js.

Even if we make it minimal like `$(document).ready(initFunction)` how do we write a test that ensures the `initFunction` is called without mocking it before the `require`?

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with this as well, the best I could come up with was just defining a function to perform all the .ready() stuff, and calling that from the tests:

**cool.js:**

```
var onReady = function() {
    $(".stuff").click(stuffClickHandler);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    onReady();
}
```

**cool_spec.js:**

```
//= require cool
fixture.load("fixture_with_stuffs.html");
onReady();
describe("on ready", function() {
  it("should bind handlers to all stuffs", function() {
    // test stuffs for handlers
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can include your cool.js at the very top of you test like this:

```
//= require cool.js
```

Comment: The original asker said that that won't work, because he wants to bind stuff to the DOM, so the DOM needs to exist _before_ the Javascript is loaded.